# How to call a WordPress page in the front-page.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want both my "about" page and my "blog" page to be part of my front/home page.

Is there a way I can call the "about" page in the `front-page.php` so that I can keep the blog part looking the same, but have an introduction to the site above it?

https://littleseabear.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional `wp_query()` in your php template for `front-page.php` to only call the one post (by ID) which contains the content of your "about" page: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: It *is*  working, you just have to get into it - it's a bit of work...

Comment: can you help me figure out where to place it if I copy the php file please?